# Spawning a child process from ASP.Net fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, process

I am trying to spawn a new process in ASP.Net on an incoming request. The new process does not get executed. It does not even throw an error in ErrorDataReceived event. However, at the same time if I supply the credential explicitly it works fine. I am supplying the same credential that I have configured in the application pool.

One more observation, child process execution fails only if it is console based app i.e. systeminfo, etc.. However, it works fine if it is WinForm app i.e. calc.exe. Of course, I cannot see the calculator on the screen, but I can see the child process calc.exe under w3wp.exe in ProcessExplorer.

Working sample code -

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(cmd)
{
     RedirectStandardError = true,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     Arguments = arguments,
     Domain = "mydomain",
     UserName = "appPoolUser",
};
startInfo.Password = new SecureString();
foreach (char ps in password)
  startInfo.Password.AppendChar(ps);

var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = startInfo,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};
process.Start();
```

If I remove the credential, it does not work.

So, why does a process does not get executed using parent process's token where at the same time it works fine if we supply the same credential that we have configured in the parent process?

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: Added sample code.